# In Oracle, how do I subtract a month from timestamp retaining the millisecond part

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

In Oracle, how do I subtract a month from timestamp retaining the millisecond part.

I am using `add_months` function but it is truncating the milliseconds. Is there a built in function or I have to manually extract month part of timestamp and add to it?

Comment: @Klas: Sorry, that question didn't turn up in my search result.

Comment: The reason is `add_months` expects a `DATE` parameter, not a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: @ Wernfried: Yes but add_months work with TIMESTAMP data type as well and I didn't realized it until I saw a problem in my result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `add_months()` function, data type conversion takes place - the value of `timestamp` data type becomes a value of `date` data type, which does not have fractional seconds.

As @jonearles absolutely correctly pointed out in a comment to the answer, using presented above method to subtract one or more months from a given value of `timestamp` data type preserving milliseconds, may cause `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

To prevent that error from popping up, the query can be rewritten as follows:

```
clear screen;

with t1(col) aS(
  select current_timestamp                     from dual union all
  select timestamp '2000-03-30 12:12:12.123'   from dual union all
  select timestamp '2014-03-30 01:12:59.64567' from dual 
)
select col as cur                                    
     , cast(add_months(col, -1) as timestamp) + (col - cast(col as date)) as prev
  from t1
```

Result:

```
CUR                                    PREV                          
-------------------------------------- -------------------------------
14-FEB-14 01.45.46.344187000 PM        14-JAN-14 01.45.46.344187000 PM  
30-MAR-00 12.12.12.123000000 PM        29-FEB-00 12.12.12.123000000 PM 
30-MAR-14 01.12.59.645670000 AM        28-FEB-14 01.12.59.645670000 AM
```

You can get it done by using year to month interval literal (can produce invalid dates):

```
clear screen;

select current_timestamp                      as res_1
     , current_timestamp - interval '1' month as res_2
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES_1                          RES_2                                
------------------------------ -----------------------------
05-FEB-14 02.02.32.383089000   05-JAN-14 02.02.32.383089000
```

Comment: SELECT current_timestamp + INTERVAL '-1' MONTH from dual; works as well.

Comment: Interval literals are usually very helpful, but unfortunately the month version has some big problems.  It simply changes the month number, which can cause invalid dates.  For example: `select date '2000-03-30' - interval '1' month from dual;`.

Comment: Do not use "interval '1' month" or "interval '1' year", as you can get invalid dates. Learned of this in production.